# Boundary Class for each Function/Form or Group of Forms

Tags: design-patterns, boundary

I saw some examples giving boundary class like LoginForm etc. That sounds correct at first glance. But in a real app where I have CRUD (4 functions at min) for each Model/Entity, isit more correct to group all functions for a single entity into 1 class?

eg.

```
<<Boundary>>    
TransactionForms
================
+ insertTransaction(...)
+ updateTransaction(...)
+ deleteTransaction(...)
+ listTransactions()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to have something like below for boundary objects,

```
FormService
 + insert(..)
 + update(..)
 + list(..)
 + delete(..).
```

Internally, those methods make use of Transaction service to update persistent layer.

```
TransactionService
  + invoke(...)
```

Comment: Erm ... is `FormService` generic, in that it handles insert for other entities too? Or did you mean something like `TransactionFormService` that uses `TransactionService`? For `TransactionService`, will invoke look like `invoke(method, params)`? Or how will it work? Which layer is it on?